# What is the difference between a HTTP Request and a HTTP GET/POST request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, request, http-post, http-get

For start - I understand the difference between GET and POST.

What I don't understand is how does a request that doesn't mention either of them work, when and why would I want to use it?

Here's an example from ASP.NET Docs:

[Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.map?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method

[MapGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mapget?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method

[MapPost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mappost?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method

Comment: The docs you listed are for creating routes for an HTTP server, not a client like it seems you think. These methods don't send a request, they receive them. As such, `Map` matches all requests regardless of request type, `MapGet` matches all requests of `GET` type, etc.

Comment: @iced " These methods don't send a request, they receive them." - This definitely makes more sense if you think of it this way, thanks. (Can't sent a request that is both GET and POST, but can receive both GET and POST requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP requests always have an HTTP method associated with them. `GET` and `POST` are two such methods, but there are others (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)).

When you call the `MapGet`, `MapPost`, or `Map` methods, you are creating "rules" that ASP.NET will use to route incoming requests to different parts of your application code, depending on which rules are matched.

Part of each rule is the route pattern itself, but you can also require a specific HTTP method in order for a rule to be matched. That's what `MapGet` and `MapPost` are doing - when you use them, they will only match requests that also have the appropriate HTTP method (`GET` and `POST`, respectively). In contrast, `Map` will match any incoming request (that also matches the route pattern), regardless of the HTTP method of the request.

This can be an easy way to get your application to behave differently depending on the HTTP method that is used. For example, you could use `MapGet` to route GET requests to a method that will return something, while using `MapPost` to route POST requests to a method that will create a new record. If you want your application to behave the same way for all requests (or you want to programmatically check the request method), you could just use `Map`.